# Setup .net 5 project without web.config after installation

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, web-setup-project

I have created a web project (.net 5) in this way :
[image]

And now, I'm trying to create a Web Setup for my .Net 5 (application console) web project. As remarked in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019), I've added published items of my website project in web setup.

When I generate my setup and install my application, I have NO **web.config** created and because of that, I have 403.14 error (when I push it manually I have no more error!).

I don't know why web.config is created automatically in handy publish from VS2019 but not in Setup Web project ? Do I have to do some configuration in my IIS or Pool or maybe in my website ? Any help or idea?

PS  App Pool is set to No Managed Code

Thanks

I need this web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MYAPP.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: "The .NET Core Runtime... option should be selected for console applications, .NET Desktop Runtime... should be selected for WPF/WinForms applications" clearly indicates the goal of that setup project is not for web apps. So you shouldn't attempt to go this route.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi for your comment. Do you have any idea how do I create a setup for web app in .net 5 ?

Comment: "Why do you need an installer for a web app?" Search the existing discussions please.

Comment: because I need it for my clients ! Any solution ?

Comment: .net 5 does not have a web.config file, because it will read the launchSettings.json not web.config. When you publish .net 5, a web.config file will be generated to tell IIS about how to use asp.net core module and handler to host the asp.net core application.

Comment: Yes, It’s completely right what you say, but web.config not generated automatically ! Do I have to configurate sth ?

Comment: No need, when you publish to iis, it will automatically create web.config file.

Comment: and here it is my problem, I give the setup file to my customer to install web app on his server, and when I test this functionality, I have no web.config after ending the setup !

Comment: Then you can try to republish project, the web.config file will be created after republishing.

Comment: I have no access to client server, that's why I need to have a complete setup for a .net5 project

Comment: There seems to be no other way.

Answer (score 1):

A console application wont have a web.config as it's not usually built to be web hosted.

Comment: I have added some more information on my post, it's the .net which create like this